# Javascript Add text to field based on multiple dropdown values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been struggling looking for a way to populate a text box based on the values of 3 separate dropdown selectors.

This is the HTML

```
<select name="dateofbirth_day" id="dateofbirth_day_field">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
    <option value="02">02</option>
</select>  
<select name="dateofbirth_month" id="dateofbirth_month_field">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="January">January</option>
    <option value="February">February</option>
</select>
<select name="dateofbirth_year" id="dateofbirth_month_year">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1980">1980</option>
    <option value="1981">1981</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="text_field" value="">
```

I need to combine the 3 values of the 3 dropdown menus above to display it in the text field as `01.January.1980`

I've used the code below to populate text fields based on the value of a dropdown but this will work only for 1 value:

```
$('#dateofbirth_day_field').change(function() {
              $('#text_field').val($('#dateofbirth_day_field option:selected').val());
         });
```

Any ideas on how to achieve the combined text with the 3 different values of the selectors?

Comment: you need to display the selected values of drop down to that textbox?

Comment: I think, it's very simple. Just get all the selected value of drop down and add all in one variable by concatenating and after that add this variable in textbox.

Comment: @JohnR Exactly. As soon as you choose the day it should display it in the text box. Then as soon as select the month it should display it in the text box separated with a dot (Example: `01.January.1980`)

Comment: @PuneetChawla Sounds interesting. Can you post your suggestion below to see how to combine those values in 1 variable?

Comment: @Mike-S122 - I have posted now. It was very easy that's why i gave you suggestion first and didn't posted but now i have posted.. After selecting year, all combined value will be display in textbox. Let me know if any doubt.

Comment: @Mike-S122 Try this fiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/y0nm8b2w/
It will not display the additional dots in textbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to bind your `change` event to all the `<select>`'s, and concatenate the values of each when any of them change:

```
var $textfield = $("#text_field");
var $month = $("#dateofbirth_month_field");
var $day = $("#dateofbirth_day_field");
var $year = $("#dateofbirth_month_year");

$('select').change(function() {
    var val = $day.val() + "." + $month.val() + "." + $year.val();
    $textfield.val(val);
});
```

And a [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/eszpyj19/6/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If it works

```
  $('#dateofbirth_day_field').change(function() {
      $('#text_field').append($('#dateofbirth_day_field option:selected').val());
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   function showSelected()
    {
        debugger;
        var day = $("#dropdown").val();
        var month = $("#dropdown1").val();
        var year = $("#dropdown2").val();
            debugger;
            var s = day+ "." + month + "." + year;
            alert(s);
            $("#txtn").val(s);

    }

</script>
```

```
<div>
 <select id="dropdown" onchange="showSelected(this)">
     <option>1</option>
     <option>2</option>
     <option>3</option>
     <option>4</option>
 </select>
      <select id="dropdown1" onchange="showSelected(this)">
     <option>11</option>
     <option>12</option>
     <option>10</option>
     <option>9</option>
 </select>
      <select id="dropdown2" onchange="showSelected(this)">
     <option>2001</option>
     <option>2002</option>
     <option>2003</option>
     <option>2004</option>
 </select>
     <input type="text" id="txtn" value="" />
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to append these fields to the textboxes

For Day change

```
  $('#dateofbirth_day_field').change(function() {
                  $('#text_field').val($('#dateofbirth_day_field option:selected').val());
             });
```

For Month change

```
$('#dateofbirth_month_field').change(function() {
                      $('#text_field').val("."+$('#dateofbirth_month option:selected').val());
                 });
```

For year Change

```
$('#dateofbirth_year_field').change(function() {
                      $('#text_field').val("."+$('#dateofbirth_year_field option:selected').val());
                 });
```

Comment: `$('#text_field').val("something")` doesn't append, it sets the value of the text field